# Garbage value being shown when reading from a file

Tags: c++, file

Two files contain integers, each of unknown count. Write a C++ program that reads such files and outputs all numbers that are common between the two files to a new file `output.txt`.

Sample input files:
File1: `12 67 83 9 -55 23 -8`
File2: `-8 57 83 77 12 -55 81 1009`

Sample output file: `12 83 -55 -8`

This is what I have tried until now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 0 };
    int arr2[] = { 0 };
    double text1 = 0;
    int text2 = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    ifstream input{ "file1.txt" };
    ofstream input2{ "file2.txt" };

    if (input)
    {
        while (input >> arr[count])
        {
            count++;
            for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                cout << arr[i];
            }
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The code is still incomplete, but I would like to know why I am being shown garbage value when I print it.

Comment: i've erased the majority of the code, the text1, text2 were meant to count the size but I dont know what to do now so that's just there

Comment: int arr[] doesn't allocate any memory and will just be a pointer on the stack.
So basically you're overwriting your own stack and corrupting your memory.

Also with C++ use of std::array, std::vector instead are prefered.

Answer (score 0):

Using a stringstream as alternative for opening a file (easier to show my intent).
It mimics a file with three lines of numbers.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // simulated file
    std::stringstream file{ "123\n234\n345\n" };

    // use vector for array that can grow when needed
    std::vector<int> arr;

    // the string read from file
    std::string input;

    while( file >> input )
    {
        // convert string to value
        int value = std::atoi(input.c_str());

        // and add value to array
        arr.push_back(value);
    } 

    // range based for loop, loops over all values in the array
    // use const int& to promise you won't change the values 
    // in the array in this loop but will only 'look' at them.
    for (const int& value : arr)
    {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for putting your time into it and explaining it but we haven't read vectors, sstream and string yet, could you try doing it without using them thanks and much appreciated!!

Comment: I don't recommend doing it using plain arrays. They're much more likely to result in bugs. 

But you could start with : const size_t buf_size = 512; and int arr[buf_size], and int arr2[buf_size] and go from there.

Just ask your teachers about std::vector, std::string, std::array they are the modern equivalents of char*, and []. They should teach them

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did but I guess they'll teach that next semester, thanks for the help though :)